# Can someone check my answers to this problem?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, finance, recursive-algorithms

This is from Discrete Mathematics and its Applications
[image: question]

Definition of recurrence relation from book
[image: definition]
From my understanding, compounded annually means that every year(annually) the account will increase by that rate.

So for 18a, to relate the current year to the previous year(recurrence relation definition) I got $b_n = 1.09b_{n-1}$  or $1.0b_{n-1} + 0.09b_{n-1}$ to show that the account increases by that 9% rate every year.

18b. I got the equation $1000(1.09)^t$ where $t$ is the number of years passed.

18c. I used my equation from 18b and got $1000(1.09)^{100}$ or \$5529040.792.

Is all of that correct? Is there a better way i could explain things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answers are mainly correct but would be easier to read if you used LaTeX

$b_n=1.09b_{n-1}$ is a better answer than $b_n=1.0b_{n-1}+0.09b_{n-1}$

$b_n =1000 \times (1.09)^n$ might be better than introducing $t$

$\$1000 \times (1.09)^{100} \approx \$5529040.79$ but you have an extra $5$ (a typo?)

Comment: Oh thanks for catching that.